# how do I retrieve the templateUrl from $modalInstance?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a custom Help for my application and
window.location.href only returns the path of the page that created the modalInstance, not the path inside of templateUrl.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be by passing templateUrl content to resolve.

```
$uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    templateUrl: function () {
      return 'myModalContent.html';
    }
  }
});
```

And then controller:

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, templateUrl) { ... }
```